# Access/manipulate history stack in R (up/down arrow)

Tags: r, shell, console, stdin

I am working on a little interactive shell-like tool in R that uses `readline` to prompt stdin, like this:

```
console <- function(){
  while(nchar(input <- readline(">>> "))) {
    message("You typed: ", input)
  }
}
```

It works but the only thing that bothers me is that lines entered this way do not get pushed upon the history stack. Pressing the up-arrow in R gives the last R command that was entered before starting the console.

Is there any way I can manually push the `input` lines upon the history stack, such that pressing the up-arrow will show the latest line entered in the console function?

Comment: The `?history` is just a text file that you could write to from your script.

Comment: I don't think that is true. It exists in memory and only gets saved at the end of your R session. I'm pretty sure the up-arrow does not query the txt file.

Comment: See the code for `savehistory`: `function (file = ".Rhistory") 
invisible(.External2(C_savehistory, file))`. I think you are savvy enough to find underlying source code. The mechanism is different for Unix-alikes versus Windoze.

Comment: Just tested this. If you do `savehistory(file="newfile")`, edit the text file to add some new lines, then do `loadhistory(file="newfile")` and hit up, you will get the line you just added.

Comment: OK thank you I got it now. I should write each line to a text file and call `loadhistory` after each command. Want to add an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this in [**rite**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rite/index.html) to add commands to the command history.  In essence, you can just `savehistory` and `loadhistory` from a local file. I do:

```
tmphistory <- tempfile()
savehistory(tmphistory)
histcon <- file(tmphistory, open="a")
writeLines(code, histcon)
close(histcon)
loadhistory(tmphistory)
unlink(tmphistory)
```

Note: [Mac doesn't use history in the same way as other OS's](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html#History), so be careful with this.